# My function is not running in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I get this code to work in the "head" tag of the HTML. I must use these two functions, and cannot use only one function. I know this is bad practice, but how would I go about doing this? Thank you for your help.

```
var myImage;
function prepareEventHandlers() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
}

function runEvents() {
    myImage.onclick = function() {
        alert('You clicked on the image.');
    };
}

window.onload = function() {
    prepareEventHandlers();
    runEvents();
}
```

Comment: What makes you think "your function is not running"? If you opened your browser's console, you would have found something like `TypeError: myImage is undefined`. So the function runs, but an error is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `var` in prepareEventHandlers(), because you are declaring a new local variable called myImage, not assigning the outer one.

```
    var myImage;

    function prepareEventHandlers() {
        myImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the "var" in your prepareEventHandlers() function.

```
var myImage;

function prepareEventHandlers() {
    myImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
}

function runEvents() {
    myImage.onclick = function() {
        alert('You clicked on the image.');
     };
}  

window.onload = function() {
    prepareEventHandlers();
    runEvents();
}
```